# SAML 2.0 LogoutRequest

Tags: logout, saml, saml-2.0

I am working on handling LogOutRequest from a replying party on the STS side.
I can parse LogoutRequest, delete the cookie and generate a LogoutResponse.
The problem is where to send the LogoutResponse, I did not find the information about reply url.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SingleLogoutService information is defined as part of the SAML 2.0 metadata that partners would exchange during setup.  That would tell you where the Single Logout handlers are, and for which binding.  I don't believe this information is typically populated in the logout request messages themselves.

Comment: This is a simple asp.net app demo, there is no metadata exchange. What is the scenario in real life? How does SAML 2.0 iDP know where to redirect after signout?

Comment: An IDP should know what SP's the user has logged into, and then upon receiving a logout request send logout requests & receive responses from all said SP's.  Again, it would know which URL's to send the request to based on partner configuration info.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you get that info in the **Issuer** element of the request.

Hope it helps,

Luis